# Android: Adding multiple buttons programmatically bug

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

So I want to add a random number of buttons(9,16,25) to form a kind of grid, on a relative layout. I want to add the buttons programmatically at the start of the activity.
For example :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

or

```
 1  2  3  4
 5  6  7  8
 9 10 11 12
13 14 15 16
```

I create an object named BOARD that contains a set of 9 TILES for example that must be arranged in a 3x3 grid

This is how I add the buttons:

```
 buttons = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int row = 0; row <  board.getNoOfRows(); row ++){
            for (int column = 0; column < board.getNoOfColumns() ; column ++){
                // first button
                if(row == 0 && column == 0){
                    buttons.add(addTile(board.getTile(currentButtonIndex) , null, null));

                }
                // next buttons on the first row
                else if(row == 0) {
                    buttons.add(addTile(board.getTile(currentButtonIndex) , buttons.get(currentButtonIndex - 1), null));

                }

                // first buttons on subsequent rows
                else if (row > 0 && column == 0){
                    buttons.add(addTile(board.getTile(currentButtonIndex) , null, buttons.get(currentButtonIndex - board.getNoOfColumns())));

                }
                // the rest of the buttons
                else if (row > 0 && column > 0){
                    buttons.add(addTile(board.getTile(currentButtonIndex) , buttons.get(currentButtonIndex - 1), buttons.get(currentButtonIndex - board.getNoOfColumns())));
                }
                // add the buttons on the view
                rlBoardView.addView(buttons.get(currentButtonIndex));
                currentButtonIndex ++;
            }
        }
        rlBoardView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

This is the addTile method:

```
private Button addTile(Tile tileParam, Button leftButton, Button aboveButton){
        Button tile = new Button(this);
        tile.setId(tileParam.getIndex());
        // setup buttons params
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        tile.setTextSize(15);
        // if button exists on the left, add it to it's right
        if(leftButton != null){
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, leftButton.getId());
        }
        // if button exists above add it below it
        if(aboveButton != null){
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, aboveButton.getId());
        }else{

        }
        tile.setLayoutParams(params);
        tile.setOnClickListener(this);
        tile.setText(String.valueOf(tileParam.getNumber()));

        return tile;
    }
```

The problem is that the resulting grid shows up as this:

```
2x2 grid   3x3 grid         4x4 grid
2          3 2              4  2  3
  3        6 4 5            8  5  6  7
             7 8           12  9 10 11 
                              13 14 15
```

The numbering starts from 0.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Some buttons are in the right places, while others are completely off. Also button 0 does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to find the problem. It was at this line:

```
tile.setId(tileParam.getIndex());
```

Although each tile had an unique index, apparently there was some kind of conflict. I replaced it with:

```
tile.setId(View.generateViewId());
```

And now everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any rules for the first button. You should probably add: ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT and ALIGN_PARENT_TOP.
So:

```
if (leftButton == null && aboveButton == null) {
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
}
```

Also for the first buttons in every next row you should add ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT.

Comment: adding the extra rules made no difference. It has the same output.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom gridView and change it as per your need. Have a look on [this sample](https://www.learn2crack.com/2014/01/android-custom-gridview.html). Good to start with.